# Diferencias entre las herramientas ASP.Net de las de un HTML normal

Tags: asp.net

Estoy empezando en esto de programar Web en ASP.Net y he visto que en Visual Studio en el cuadro de herramientas puedes poner un `<asp:Button>` y cosas de este estilo. 
¿En qué cambiaría un `<asp:Button>` de un `<Button>` , como si fuera un `HTML` normal?

Comment: Es una pregunta válida. Diferencia entre Button i asp:Button.

Comment: Yo voté para cerrar porque el OP no había formateado las etiquetas (no se veía lo de los buttons) y no se entendía nada, luego me he dado cuenta que era por eso y la he editado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno la diferencia entre un `<asp:button>` y un `<button>` es que el `<asp:button>` tiene muchas propiedades accesibles por código mientras el `<button>` normal tienes que colocarlas por `CSS` o `Javascript`.

`ASP.Net` es un **framework** que tiene muchas cosas ya hechas solo para que tu las uses a tu mejor conveniencia... entre estas manipulación de base de datos, `HTML` solo es el maqueado de datos...

Si vas iniciar con web, busca algún **framework** que se te acomodo es lo mejor para trabajar... claro que puedes hacer todo con `HTML, CSS y Javascript`... pero es mas practico y rápido trabajar con frameworks... hay varios `ASP.Net(mvc), Ruby on Rails, PHP Laravel`... el que mas te guste...

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias .Ya me ha quedado claro.

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero de todo, tu pregunta no es muy legible. Pero creo entender lo que estas preguntado.

Microsoft mismo te dice las siguientes características:

ASP.NET incluye:

- Marco de trabajo de página y controles
- Compilador de ASP.NET
- Infraestructura de seguridad
- Funciones de administración de estado
- Configuración de la aplicación
- Supervisión de estado y características de rendimiento
- Capacidad de depuración
- Marco de trabajo de servicios Web XML
- Entorno de host extensible y administración del ciclo de vida de las
- aplicaciones
- Entorno de diseñador extensible

Yo personalmente, llevo bastante trabajando con asp.net y debo decirte que, si vas a crear un proyecto medianamente grande, te sera de gran ayuda utilizar esta tecnología, de lo contrario, si es un pequeño proyecto, la curva de aprendizaje es bastante grande, por lo que no te recomendaría utilizarla, y limitarme al html puro con php.

Answer (score 0):

La principal diferencia es el acceso al control desde tu codigo .net, si defines un  podras accederlo por su nombre desde el codigo asociado a la pagina, el aspx.cs, mientras que un tag html no podras hacerlo, salvo que el definas la propiedad runat="server" con lo cual lo conviertes en un html control.

[Información general sobre los controles de servidor Web ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/zsyt68f1(v=vs.100).aspx)

En el articulo explica la diferencia entre los "Controles de servidor HTML" y los "Controles de servidor Web", esta claro que los controles que asp.net provee permiten controlar el render y acceder a una gama mas amplia de eventos en el servidor

Answer (score 0):

Un  es un control del servidor, esto incluye código JavaScript que realiza las llamadas [PostBack](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/6654992b-a112-496d-a623-e0af352a5bbf/acerca-de-postback?forum=netfxwebes) (es la comunicacion del cliente con el servidor cuando se lanza un evento de un control de ASP.Net), a diferencia del `<button>` de `HTML` que solo se renderea en el explorador con las propiedades definidas.